# How to use clang-format from macports?

Tags: clang, macports, clang-format

I would like to use `clang-format`, but I can't find it in my system. I have llvm installed from macports. What is the way to install/enable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install clang to get the clang tools (and llvm is a dependency of clang, so you are half way there). To get the latest stable version as of this post via macports use

`sudo port install clang-3.9`

Now for me clang-format is then installed in `/opt/local/libexec/llmv-3.9/bin`. In here you will find all the other clang tools too, such as clang-tidy.

For simplicity I made an alias in my bash profile, since I do not like the Apple's `fmt` command: `alias fmt ='/opt/local/libexec/llmv-3.9/bin/clang-format'`. Therefore `fmt -i file.c` now runs clang-format inplace (overwrites file) with the styles I picked in my `.clang-format` file.

As an added bonus this is an amazing tool to help test what all the clang-format options do: http://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/

Comment: Thanks! I have the directory you mention, but there is no clang-tidy or clang-format there.

Comment: @gruszczy if you run `port contents clang-3.9` what is a bunch of stuff returned? Moreover, what version of llvm did you port install? If you have llvm-3.9 then use that command, else use `port contents clang-$(version)` if you have llvm-$(version). If you have stuff installed, tell me instead what `port contents clang-3.9 | grep "/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.9/bin"` returns. If the first command returns results, but the second doesn't then for some reason clang tools weren't installed where I thought they'd be.

Comment: `find /opt/local -name "clang-format"` if nothing is returned you might have failed to build clang with macports. Another possibility is that you custom installed macports and changed the default path such that installations are not done in /opt/local.

Comment: @gruszczy Also, I should mention you would have `/opt/local/libexec/llmv-3.9/bin` from your llvm install. **This does not mean you have or should have clang tools.** When you install clang, it will also use the same directory.

Comment: Finally, I have time to come back to this. Thanks a lot, this worked.

Answer (score 12):

First install clang-3.9 with MacPorts with the command

```
sudo port install clang-3.9
```

Afterwards, you will find `clang-format-mp-3.9` in `/opt/local/bin` which should already be in your PATH so you can just use it.

If you want to make `clang` and all other related tools point to the version you just installed, you can use the select mechanism of MacPorts.

You can see all available choices with `port select --list` for clang.

```
$ port select --list clang
Available versions for clang:
    mp-clang-3.8
    mp-clang-3.9
    none (active)
```

With `sudo port select --set clang <version>` you choose one of them as the new default, which will create symlinks in `/opt/local/bin` without the version suffix.

```
$ sudo port select --set clang mp-clang-3.9
Selecting 'mp-clang-3.9' for 'clang' succeeded. 'mp-clang-3.9' is now active.
```

You can confirm this change by looking at the version of the tool:

```
$ clang-format --version
clang-format version 3.9.0 (tags/RELEASE_390/final)
```

If you later wish to remove these symlinks in order to avoid hiding tools installed by Xcode, just select the `none` version.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of clang is 8.0:

```
$ sudo port install clang-8.0
$ clang
clang                            clang-check-mp-7.0               clang-format-mp-8.0              clang-offload-bundler-mp-7.0     clang-reorder-fields-mp-7.0
clang++                          clang-check-mp-8.0               clang-func-mapping-mp-7.0        clang-offload-bundler-mp-8.0     clang-reorder-fields-mp-8.0
clang++-mp-7.0                   clang-cl-mp-7.0                  clang-import-test-mp-7.0         clang-query-mp-7.0               clang-tidy-mp-7.0
clang++-mp-8.0                   clang-cl-mp-8.0                  clang-import-test-mp-8.0         clang-query-mp-8.0               clang-tidy-mp-8.0
clang-apply-replacements-mp-7.0  clang-cpp-mp-7.0                 clang-include-fixer-mp-7.0       clang-refactor-mp-7.0            clangd-mp-7.0
clang-apply-replacements-mp-8.0  clang-cpp-mp-8.0                 clang-include-fixer-mp-8.0       clang-refactor-mp-8.0            clangd-mp-8.0
clang-change-namespace-mp-7.0    clang-extdef-mapping-mp-8.0      clang-mp-7.0                     clang-rename-mp-7.0              clangd-xpc-test-client-mp-8.0
clang-change-namespace-mp-8.0    clang-format-mp-7.0              clang-mp-8.0                     clang-rename-mp-8.0
```

So clang-format-mp-8.0 at /opt/local/bin/ is the one.